An indecomposable $\mathbb{C}[x]$ module that is not simple
I would like to check my understanding of the ideas of simple and irreducible modules of a ring $R$ for the case where $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$.
If $R=\mathbb{C}[x]$, then since $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is commutative, a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module is simple (i.e., irreducible, i.e, containing no proper nonzero submodules) if and only if $M\cong\mathbb{C}[x]/I$, where $I$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x]$.
But the maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ are the $\langle x-\alpha\rangle$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence all simple $\mathbb{C}[x]$-modules are isomorphic to some $\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x-\alpha\rangle$. But $\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x-\alpha\rangle\cong\mathbb{C}$. Hence $\mathbb{C}$ is the only simple $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module.
Now, I'd like to characterize the $\mathbb{C}[x]$-modules $M$ that are indecomposable (i.e., that cannot be written as a direct sum of non-trivial submodules) but not simple. I think that we can pick any abelian group not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ that is not simple (if $G$ is a simple abelian group, then $G$ is simple as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module) and that cannot be written as a direct sum. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module that is indecomposable but not simple.

Are these arguments correct? What is the proper characterization of all $\mathbb{C}[x]$-modules that are indecomposable but not simple?


What would be the $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module structure on $\mathbb{R}$?
A $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module is nothing more than a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $V$ with a distinguished endomorphism $u\in \mathcal{L}(V)$. It is indecomposable if there is no non-trivial decomposition $V=U\oplus W$ with $U$ and $W$ $u$-stable, and it is simple if $u$ has no non-trivial stable subspace.
So for instance just take $V$ some $\mathbb{C}$-vector space of dimension $n>1$, and $u$ some endomorphism of $V$ which is nilpotent of index $n$. Then the corresponding $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module is indecomposable, because if we had $V=U\oplus W$ with $U$ and $W$ $u$-stable, then the nilpotency index of $u$ would be at most $\max(\dim(U),\dim(W))$, so $U$ or $W$ must be $V$. And it is not simple because for instance $\ker(u)$ is a non-trivial stable subspace.

I presume you meant a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space

Yes, faulty copy-paste.

Could you say why "A $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module is nothing more than a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space with a distinguished endomorphism?"

Is it that $u$ is the operation $\mathbb{C}[x]\times\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^n$ associated to the module?
